# Python Random.choice() not receiving arguments

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey", "yo", "whats up"]

def greet(message):
    greet = Random.choice(greetings)
    return f"{greet} @{message.author}"
```

When I run this I get the error:
`TypeError: choice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seq'`
Though I am clearly passing `greetings` into `choice()`

Comment: Try lowercase random. `random.choice(greetings)`

Comment: `Random`, or `random`? `random.Random` is a *class*, in which case `Random` would expect two arguments: an instance of `Random` and the sequence to choose from.

Comment: `random.choice`, on the other hand, is a convenience wrapper around a predefined instance of `Random`.

Comment: This is another reason to avoid `from ... import *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from your code what `Random` is.
However, if you import the `random` module and replace `Random` with `random`, your code should work.

Here is a fully working example (together with a Message class).

```py
import random 

greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey", "yo", "whats up"]

def greet(message):
    greet = random.choice(greetings)
    return f"{greet} @{message.author}"

class Message: 
    def __init__(self, msg, author): 
        self.msg = msg 
        self.author = author 
        
msg = Message('Hello', 'Peter')
print(greet(msg))
# Prints e.g.: 'hi @Peter'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
greetings = "Hi", "Hello", "Hey", "Yo", "Whats up"
author = 'Stanly'

def greet(message):
    greet = random.choice(greetings)
    return f"{greet} @{author}!"
print(greet(greetings))
```

Answer (score 1):

The questions on the top is correct but here is one with `Discord.PY` (because I noticed some things that belong to it.) and also with *`async`*

```py
import random


greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey", "yo", "whats up"]

async def greet(message, greetings):
    greet = random.choice(greetings)
    return f"{greet}, @{message.author}"
```

if you are posting in stack overflow please tag more things other than just `Python`,
it helps more people try to understand what you are doing and what you want us to do.

Comment: What does `async` have to do with the question?